# why is the line in my card list group is not fully consumed,what do you think is the problem with that?

Tags: bootstrap-4

This is my code for the card:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header text-white bg-dark">Header</div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Buy Now</button></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg3Tp.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/coyzrjqp/2/

Comment: I see it's good with what you show to me,but why's that it's incomplete to me like i showed in the picture.what do you think is the problem am i put bootstrap incorrectly or something?

Comment: I don't know. You probably will need to show more, like other layouts around it, additional custom CSSs you wrote, how you reference Bootstrap, etc.